# Export Powershell output to user desktop (User desktop varies)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

i am running a powershell to export Exchange online user data in a TXT file where i have mentioned `C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop\Getdata.txt` as a location but this script runs on different computer where we have different users so i want to export the data to the desktop of the user directly

Script is as such

```
Start-Transcript
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session 
get-mailbox |FT >C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop\Getdata.txt
Stop-Transcrip
```

I am still not able to export data to the desktop. I cant export data on `C:\` directly as users donot have permission on any local disks.Can this be possible keeping the powershell intact till get-mailbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the current user's Desktop path you can get that with:

```
[environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
```

So for your code:

```
|FT > (join-path ([environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')) "GetData.txt")
```

Comment: so will it be Like this?
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session 
get-mailbox |FT >[environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

Comment: That would redirect the output of the command to the folder, but you would need to specify a file name as well.

Comment: I got an error : Join-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'GetData.txt'.
At line:1 char:20
+ get-mailbox |FL > (join-path [environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') "GetData.tx ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand